# Script table as CREATE TO by using vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

In SQL server I can create a table which is duplicate of another table with all constraints set in it. I can use script table as CREATE TO in SQL server management studio to do this. Then I can run the script in another database so that same table is recreated but without data. I want to do same by using vb.net code. Important point is that all the constraints and table properties are set properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the SMO (SQL Server Management Objects) assembly to script out tables to a string inside your application. I'm using C# here, but the same can be done easily in VB.NET, too.

```
// Define your database and table you want to script out
string dbName = "YourDatabase";
string tableName = "YourTable";

// set up the SMO server objects - I'm using "integrated security" here for simplicity
Server srv = new Server();
srv.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = true;
srv.ConnectionContext.ServerInstance = "YourSQLServerInstance";

// get the database in question
Database db = new Database();
db = srv.Databases[dbName];

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

// define the scripting options - what options to include or not
ScriptingOptions options = new ScriptingOptions();
options.ClusteredIndexes = true;
options.Default = true;
options.DriAll = true;
options.Indexes = true;
options.IncludeHeaders = true;

// script out the table's creation 
Table tbl = db.Tables[tableName];

StringCollection coll = tbl.Script(options);

foreach (string str in coll)
{
    sb.Append(str);
    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
}

// you can get the string that makes up the CREATE script here
// do with this CREATE script whatever you like!
string createScript = sb.ToString();
```

You need to reference several SMO assemblies.

Read more about SMO and how to use it here:

- [Getting Started with SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1826/getting-started-with-sql-server-management-objects-smo/)
- [Generate Scripts for database objects with SMO for SQL Server](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1833/generate-scripts-for-database-objects-with-smo-for-sql-server/)